# SQL Server 2012 patching failure - The language of SQL Server instance MSSQLSERVER does not match the language expected by the SQL Server update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, patching

I've picked up the support for a SQL Server 2012 instance on a server at our German site and need to apply SQLServer2012SP4-KB4018073-x64-ENU.

The patching is failing with the installer showing error

> The language of SQL Server instance MSSQLSERVER does not match the language expected by the SQL Server update. The installed SQL Server product language is German (Germany) and the expected SQL Server language is English (United States).

The server properties general tab (in SSMS) shows Language **German (Germany)**, but the SERVERPOPERTY('LCID') shows **1033 (US_English)**. The registry entry shows 1031 (German) as the install language (https://www.sqlserverscience.com/basics/localization/language-used-sql-server-binaries/#comment-191)

[image]

Trying to use the German patch file SQLServer2012SP4-KB4018073-x64-DEU results in

> This SQL Server setup media does not support the language of the OS, or does not have the SQL Server English-language version installation files. Use the matching language-specific SQL Server media; or install both the language specific MUI and change the format and system locales through the regional settings in the control panel

Any pointers as to a way forward so I can apply the patch?

Attempted patching after first suggested fix

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The cause](https://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting104.htm) of the error is that you are applying an English update on a SQL Server installed in German language. Or maybe there might be some specific problem with SQL Server and the [German Language](https://superuser.com/questions/1212957/installing-sql-server-2016-under-windows-10-language-problems).

@Massimiliano Buschi is right, the solution should be [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyKrin3wmT0). However you said in your case is not working.

**Use PowerShell to:**

1. Check your current language: `Get-WinUserLanguageList`
2. Set the language you want: `Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList en-US`
3. Reboot and try to install

**Still doesn't work? Let's try to change [these 3 parameters](https://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting176.htm):**

1. `User interface settings:` In Control Panel, open Region and Language. On the Languages ​​tab, for Language used in menus and dialogs, select a value from the list. Click Apply to confirm the change and OK to close the window.
2. `User locale:` In Control Panel, open Regional and Language Options. On the Regional Options tab, for Select an item to display its settings, select a value from the list. Click Apply to confirm the change and OK to close the window.
3. `System locale:` In Control Panel, open Regional and Language Options. On the Advanced tab, for Select a language that matches the version of the non-Unicode programs you want to use, select a value from the list. Click Apply to confirm the change and OK to close the window.

**Still doesn't work? We need to use the hammer :(**

1. Delete or Rename the `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\110` folder (110 for SQL Server 2012, 120 for SQL Server 2014and so on)
2. Try again.

Comment: Thanks - I will try again when I can get another maintenance window

Comment: This solution (part 1) works to allow me to run the DEU install media, thanks. I had been looking at the issue of trying to allow the ENU installer to perform the update.

Comment: @MikeSpencer-Jones, just for clarification: are you referring to the PowerShell part? Was this a solution for you or do you wanted to install the ENG instead of DEU? Because I don't get if this solved the problem for you or not. If it solved please label my reply as the right one so more people will take it as the solution

Comment: I used the Powershell to check the setting, then changed it in Control Panel before trying the DEU install exe. Previously I have done the same, but attempted to install the ENU version believing, incorrectly, that it was the correct one as it had been used on other servers at the site.

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy one. Albeit if you work in a Swiss-German organisation like I do and have to install German SQL Server instances on Windows Servers, which have been set up to use the location Switzerland which results in a Swiss-German keyboard layout and date-time settings.

The solution depends on the version of the OS installed...

## Windows Server 2016

On a Window Server 2016 with the Location set to Switzerland the language bar might look like this:
[image: Windows Language Bar Location Switzerland]

Trying to install a German Service Pack will fail, even though the **Deutsch (Schweiz)** setting is available. Starting the `SQLServer2016SP2-KB4052908-x64-DEU.exe` (SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 2 German) results in:

[image: SQL Server Setup Error Message for Language]

### Solution

To circumvent this issue, add the language **German - German** and set to default.

#### 1. Open Language and Region Settings

[image: Language and Region Settings]

Click on the **Add Language** icon ...

#### 2. Add Language

...and start typing **German**.

[image: Add German Language]

#### 3. Select German - German

Select the **German (Germany)** (*or **Deutsch (Deutschland)***) option...

[image: Deutsch (Deutschland) option]

#### 4. Set Default

...and when back in the Language and Region Settings select the **Set Default** button:

[image: Set Language Default]

#### 6. Language and Region Settings

Your settings should now look a bit like this with **German (Germany)** (*or **Deutsch (Deutschland)***) at the top.

[image: Geman (Germany) as Default Language]

#### 6. Run Setup Again

If I run the setup for Service Pack 2 now, then I am presented with:

[image: Setup Executing for German Language]

...and eventually this:

[image: License Terms SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 2]

> **Disclaimer:**
> All pictures taken today on a Windows Server 2019 (German) running SQL Server 2016 (German)

*Details for older operating systems to follow...*

Comment: Thanks, this has helped too

Answer (score 1):

Please try to go to Control Panel, Regional Settings and change the "Format" language.  close , re-open it and change format back to yours. Retry the setup of the patch

Comment: Hi, I have tried that and I am still having the same issue in the installer. I have added screen print to original post to show.

Comment: Thanks, this did work when I used the correct install media!

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 Files:

SQLServer2012SP4-KB4018073-x64-ENU.exe

SQLServer2012SP4-KB4018073-x64-DEU.exe

1. Unpack both files
2. Copy the files from DEU (or your language setup) to ENU folder
3. Run the SETUP.EXE

PS - If you copy the ENU to DEU (or your language setup folder), it will not work